# How to change the wsdl:definitions name attribute on a BizTalk service

Tags: wcf, biztalk, wcf-binding, biztalk-2013

I've published schema as a wcf service, choosing WCF-CustomIsolated with a binding type of customBinding.  I can now browse to the web service and look at the wsdl.  All good so far, but I do have some questions about how I configure the receive location to make some specific changes in the wsdl:

1. Change the wsdl:definitions name attribute.  It is set to BizTalkServiceInstance by default
2. Change the wsdl:service name attribute.  It is also set to BizTalkServiceInstance by default

Answer (score 1):

For this you need either implement custom WCF wsdl extension or write your own wsdl and use that for contract. This link will give you some idea. [Custom Types in wsdl](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2009/05/22/how-to-throw-typed-fault-exceptions-from-orchestrations-published-as-wcf-services.aspx). Although this link is for faults however it will give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

On your WCF-Custom receive port, add the WCF behavior `serviceMetadata`.

Add the path to your custom WSDL file (you need to copy it in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\\your.wsdl for example). 
FYI: in this case your path would be "../your.wsdl" for example.

[image]

Then, set `httpGetEnabled` to `true`.

Edit your wsdl as you like.